# PHP < 5.3 => Difference in hours between two dates

Tags: php, date, time, difference

In a current project I have hit a wall because I need to compare two dates and find the difference between the dates (in hours), this would be easy if the server was >= 5.3, can someone help me?

I have the difference in timestamp

`$diff = abs(strtotime($date1)-strtotime($date2)`

but I don't know what to do next...

Thank you.

Comment: Please check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php?rq=1  It explains the old way (`strtotime`) and new way (`DateTime`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `$diff` is the difference in seconds. You can convert the seconds to hours like this:

```
$hours = floor($diff / (60 * 60));
```

**Edit:** To get minutes and seconds:

```
$minutes = floor(($diff - $hours * 60 * 60) / 60);
$seconds = floor($diff - $hours * 60 * 60 - $minutes * 60);
```

Comment: Simpler would be $minutes=$diff/60;

Comment: @AnthonyScaife It's not the same. It would just convert the difference  (which is in seconds) to minutes which doesn't make sense. OP wants to display the difference as hours:minutes:seconds.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing!
How can I check if $date2 is less from 10 hours away from $date1?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo round((strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2))/(60*60));
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, now I just need to find out how to show this as H:m:s (like 36hours:27minutes:12seconds), is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your code $diff is in seconds. 
There are 3600 seconds in an hour, so:

```
$date1 = "2014-07-15";
$date2 = "2014-07-17";

$diff_seconds = abs(strtotime($date1)-strtotime($date2));
$diff_hours = $diff_seconds/3600;

echo $diff_seconds.' '.$diff_hours;
```